# Need a way to set a form submission to show it is coming from the sender using email field

Tags: php, forms, email, reply

I have a form that people fill out. It sends me an email when they submit. I want the email to show it is from the person sending it. Their email is one of the fields. I want to be able to hit reply to reply to them.

This is the code I am using:

```
 mail($_POST["e_mail"]."myaddress@email.com", $_POST['e-mail']." Interested in Cajun Catering", "Name: ".$_POST['Name'] ."\n"."Address: ".$_POST['address']."\n"."City: ".$_POST['city']."\n"."E-Mail: ".$_POST['e_mail']."\n"."Phone: ". $_POST['phone']."\n"."Time to call: ".$_POST['call']."\n"."Products: ".$_POST['Prod1']."     ".$_POST['Prod2']."     ".$_POST['Prod3']."     ".$_POST['Prod4']."   \n"."Type:   ".$_POST['type']."\n"."Event Date: ".$_POST['event_date']."\n"."Number of Guests: ".$_POST['Number']."\n"."Comments: ".$_POST['comments'],'From: '.$_POST['e_mail']);
```

Comment: 1. Don’t use `mail`, use a proper mailer class like PHPMailer or Swift Mail. 2. Set their email address as `Reply-To`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `-f` option with `mail()`:

```
$to = "youremailaddress@email.com";
$subject = "The subject";
$message = "The message";
$from = "FROM: returnaddress@email.com";
$return = "-freturnaddress@email.com"

mail($to, $subject, $message, $from, $return);
```

Note that `$return` contains the same email address as `$from`, preceded by `-f`

Comment: I notice a lot of people doing your way but I have the data sent through the form coming in the email. Can I do that in $message?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question ... you can put whatever you want into `$message` ... including data from a form.